# How to assert stdout statements from JMeter logs?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

We have a beanshell test that executes a JAR, that in turn, prints the response on stdout; very similar to the process described in [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-custom-jar-beanshell-sampler-jmeter-lakshmi-narayan/) article. However, I'm wondering if there is a way to validate the statements printed in the log as part of the tests without resorting to manual verification.

Answer (score 0):

1. Forget about Beanshell, [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)
2. Your test design looks very flaky ang vague, however if you cannot think of a better option than capturing stdout you can create your own [PrintStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) and use [System.setOut()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut(java.io.PrintStream)) function to use your own PrintStream instead of STDOUT. Something like:

   - Add [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test/) to your Test Plan
   - Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to the setUp Thread Group
   - Put the following code into "Script| area:

     ```
     def baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
     def ps = new PrintStream(baos)
     System.setOut(ps)
     props.put('baos', baos)
     ```
   - Once done you can access all the messages which were printed to the STDOUT using the following code:

     ```
     def stdout = props.get('baos').toString()
     ```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: I don’t think gathering the logs in memory is a practical solution for load testing, that is meant to generate a ton of traffic, and hence logs.